# VBA, array looping, subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting `subscript out of range error 9` on my 2nd lineof the For loop below.
i = 7 (row number), and c1 = 59, c2=60 (column numbers). Why am I not getting subscript out of range here?

Should I be using `1` or `2` instead of `c1` or `c2`?  When I use `1` or `2` it is not picking up my columns correctly.

```
Dim c1 As Variant
Dim c2 As Variant
Dim arr() as Variant

Set rw = ws.Rows(6)
lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

c1 = Application.Match("Col 59)", rw, 0)
c2 = Application.Match("Col 60", rw, 0)

If Not IsError(c1) And Not IsError(c2) Then    'found both column headers?
    arr = ws.Range(rw.Cells(c1), rw.Cells(c2)).Resize(lastR).Value2
Else
    MsgBox "One or both required column headers not found!"
End If
    

'Loop to find Empty and Non empty fields
For i = 7 To UBound(arr) 'Row 7 is the row the data starts
    If (arr(i, c1) <> "" And arr(i, c2) = "") Or (arr(i, c2) <> "" And arr(i, c1) = "") Then        
        addToRange rngCopy, ws.Range("A" & i)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I highly suggest you read [Arrays and Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Comment: `arr(1,1)` would correspond to  `rw.Cells(c1)` (so on Row 6 not Row 1, and column c1 not column 1)  You can't use cell coordinates (row/column) if you didn't pick up the array starting at A1.

Comment: hi tim, i = 7 and c1 =59 , wouldnt this mean 7th row of the 59th column and then iterate downwards?

Comment: Your array values start from `rw.Cells(c1)`, not from range A1.

Comment: I do `rw=6` because thats where i read the headers

Comment: If you pick up an array `arr` from (eg) C3:E6 then `arr(1,1)` is the value from C3 and `arr(4,3)` is the value from E6.

Comment: so I should use, `If (arr(i, 1) <> "" And arr(i, 2)` ? this seems to get rid of the error. but Not picking up values/not passing the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out - more code, but it saves you from needing to do any math on the array vs. range coordinates:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Const HEADER_ROW As Long = 6
    Dim c1 As Variant, c2 As Variant, ws As Worksheet, rw As Range, lastR As Long
    Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, v1, v2
    Dim i As Long, rngCopy As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or some other specific sheet
    Set rw = ws.Rows(HEADER_ROW)
    lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    c1 = Application.Match("Col 59)", rw, 0)
    c2 = Application.Match("Col 60", rw, 0)
    
    If Not IsError(c1) And Not IsError(c2) Then    'found both column headers?
        'define two ranges to pick up values from
        Set rng1 = ws.Range(rw.Cells(c1), ws.Cells(lastR, c1))
        Set rng2 = ws.Range(rw.Cells(c2), ws.Cells(lastR, c2))
        'fill the arrays
        arr1 = rng1.Value2
        arr2 = rng2.Value2
    Else
        MsgBox "One or both required column headers not found!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    'Loop to find Empty and Non empty fields
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr1, 1) 'i=1 would be the column headers
        v1 = arr1(i, 1)         'read the two values to be compared
        v2 = arr2(i, 1)
        If (v1 <> "" And v2 = "") Or (v1 = "" And v2 <> "") Then
            addToRange rngCopy, ws.Cells(rng1.Cells(i).Row, "A")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Tim.  getting an error on `object required` on line `Set rng1 = ws.Range(rw.Cells(c1), ws.Cells(lastR, c1.Column))`

Comment: Sorry my bad - see edits above `ws.Cells(lastR, c1)` not `ws.Cells(lastR, c1.Column)`  Same for the next line.